# Surface deform with geometry nodes

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes, surface-deform

I want to this object [image]

cover with this [image]

to make this sofa: [image]

Im taking UV from object and putting weave on it then deform it in initial object.
My geometry nodes setup: [image]

Weave purfectly fit uv but problem is that it did not deform back in original shape correctly. Weave flat after deforming.
[image]
Can you pls tell me what i do wrong?

Comment: For this you should rather use a *Shader* instead of *Geometry Nodes*. I'm pretty sure @Crantisz would get that done with a few nodes ;-)

Comment: Maybe. But the goal is to make it with geometry nodes.

Comment: OK, this will certainly be fun. Do you have any idea how you want the transitions at the edges to look? ...especially with the curvature it might be difficult. How do you want the geometry to run there?

Comment: Literaly no idea... one step at the time... I was thining about carefuly and strategically placed uv island so transition wont be noticible, but i have my doubts...

Comment: Yes, me too, which is why I advise you to use a shader here. In your example photo, it's not clear how the transition at the edges is designed, and how the fibers run here. Also, you won't be able to solidly match an existing mesh with GN to this shape (at least not with reasonable effort) and creating the mesh in GN requires a more detailed plan of how the result should look at the edges. ...just my tip on this.

Comment: At least, according to my estimation, this is relatively complex, even if it may look simple. And since you don't understand the "stolen" nodes either, I doubt anyone here is really rebuilding this thing for you. So in my opinion, the question should rather aim for a solution with shaders, or be closed.

Comment: Its not your place to tell me that i cant understand the answer. If you don't have anything helpful to say, pls just go away.

Comment: .... I'm very sorry that you feel attacked, but I really wanted to help you. And in the end, you were the one who said he only understood half of the stolen nodes.

Comment: If i understood them all i would not need to post questions here, I could have done all by myself... Always thought this is the place to ask questions when you dont understand stuff. My misstake i guess...

Comment: @Psion quellenform
 is trying to help, You should try and collaborate with the people trying to understand your issue, rather that drive them away

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos He literaly told me that i should do shaders like he said or close the question. Im sorry, but this anything but collaboration. Question was about geo nodes. Not shaders.

Comment: I wanted to help you, and I just wanted to tell you that the question, as it is currently formulated, does not specify the task clearly enough for *Geometry Nodes*. Closing a question is basically the way to react to unclearly formulated questions. As soon as the question is informative and the task is clearly formulated, I am sure that people can be found here on BSE who can help you. Since you yourself have given to understand that you are actually not clear on what exactly this should look like, I would suggest that you tweak your question. All this was not meant in a bad or personal way.

Comment: @quellenform I have no idea how more clearly can i ask question "Why weave come out flat?" I didnt ask anything more than that. Well, whatever, close, dont close, i dont care anymore...

Comment: It comes out flat because you use `Transfer Attribute` and `Set Position` to move all points to the nearest position of the underlying shape. But you're right, I have interfered too much here. Sorry about that, good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a fairly unrefined version of a possible strategy.

[image]

- Save the target's 'Position' attribute, before..
- Splitting the target's edges and flattening its geometry to its own UV Map.
- Fire rays down from a sheet of wrapper geometry onto the flattened target
- Use 'Hit' to trim wrapper-sheet
- Pick up the pre-flattened target Position from the ray
- Warp the wrapper using that position

(This is the step I think you're looking for....)

- Thicken the wrapper by some scale of its original Z, along (the unflattened ) target's transferred Normal.

[image]

'Unrefined', because there's probably a nicer way of handling seams, reducing gaps. But this is maybe a start.

[image]

**Edit**

In response to commentary. The best luck I've had so far with a trim to cover seams, maintaining a half-decent topology, is to delete the original mesh where it is not close to UV seams, and extrude the rest:

[image]

With this sort of result.. it's pretty twitchy, but with careful attention to bevelling the original, seam placement, and scaling UV islands, could be OK:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But i got some distortion waves https://imgur.com/a/6hpEedn If i decrease mutliply value on wraper to lessen the destortion, weave became almost flat again :(

Comment: Hi, @Psion ! Can you share a faulty sample on blend-exchange? It may help 'refine' the answer.

Comment: Sure. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rUBAMw1a3UzNv0-w4pEIjVMgQzCd4DEy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Psion attending to it. The main problem has been the base geometry (inconsistent normals, duplicate vertices, etc.) But, even having cleaned that up, your example has thrown up an edge-case in the GN modifier,  which I think I've diagnosed OK, (ray-cast is prone to floating-point error) ... so trying to find a neat fix for that.

Comment: @Psion Okydoky, so far, so good. Any other problems, ideas for tweaks, fire away. [Here's the file](https://blend-exchange.com/b/sxENOYRD/). You could, for example, arrange for a trim to be put over seams, just like in RL,

Comment: Amazing! It works! :) Tnx so much. Was banging on this wall for a week now. My idea for seam edges was to carefuly place weave so that it merges with other parts. Is it even posible to make it automatically? Or only by hands?

Comment: @Psion I was having fun thinking of ways to make a trim. But lining  the weave up automatically  would be very tricky, I think, unless you made some sort of procedural weave in 3D space, like a shader, maybe .. worth a thought, but I _think_ the automation would be so case-by-case for the wrappers that by hand is probably better and quicker. .. you never know, there are some very cunning folks here.. :)

Comment: I was afraid of this. Wanted to make it all procedural, it would have been so cool :) Well about trim, i added node to isolate trims but dont know how to wrap them. Sadly i yet to fully understand your nodes :(  https://blend-exchange.com/b/eBrjydmy

Comment: @Psion OK, some progress, see edit to answer, The best way to understand the processes in a GN tree, I've found, is to Shift-Alt Click nodes to see the output of various branches. (Node Wrangler must be  installed)

Comment: Yea, i know about wrangler, without it there no chance to understand any node setup :) So i tried to look up how this done in other 3d application. And found out that in 3ds max there Ornatrix weaver modifier. It uses splines and UV islands that very close to each other to seamlesly connect edges. Here, maybe it be of some use: https://youtu.be/RZbY6d9DY0M?t=214